# How to sort arrays alphabetically, punctuation symbols holding precedence

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

So if I have a string array such as:

```
array = { "Carol", "`-=[]\;',.//uF18*-+~!@#$*"};
```

how would I sort it so punctuation symbols are first in the re-assortment?  Using Arrays.sort(array) will put these after any  strings with alphabetical beginnings. the goal is for it to be:

```
 array = {"`-=[]\;',.//uF18*-+~!@#$*", "Carol"}
```

after sorting.

Comment: Did you try implementing a custom `Comparator`?

Comment: Use a custom `Comparator` to define the rules of how elements should be sorted against each other - and before you ask for an example - know, there are number of countless examples available for you to research

Comment: I'll research Comparators, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like collation, which is typically based on a custom character sequence.  E.g. a `RuleBasedCollator` will let you define how different chars relate to each other:

```
Collator collator = new RuleBasedCollator("< '`','-','=' < A,B,C");
String[] array = { "Carol", "`-=[]\\;',.//uF18*-+~!@#$*"};
Arrays.sort(array, collator);
```

That's been kept short for readability, but clearly you'll need to work through more characters in those rules.  There's usually no need to go too far though - any characters you leave out just revert to their normal sequence, after the ones in the rules.  And note punctuation chars tend to need to be quoted.

`RuleBasedCollator` does have quite a bit more going on in these rules though.  For example it can handle multi-letter grouping before sorting, e.g. `"< c < ch < d"` for Spanish.  If in doubt, take a look at the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html).